# how to change Ip address binding through PHP CPanel

Tags: php, asp.net, cpanel

Earlier i have purchased a web space of PHP and a domain name .
Now i have purchased another web sapce of ASP.net .I want to bind my existing domain name with my new Web space.
So through some google search i came to know to i have to make Entry of the new server's Ip in the DNS zone. In my previous PHP's Cpanel i m having the following window.
Should i make entry from here , and what should I enter at these textboxes.
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to change the nameservers at your domain registrar to your new host's nameservers which should be provided in their welcome email.